# Angularjs ng-show method

Tags: angularjs

I have this angular application where I want to display some data based on permissions so on my main controller I'm fetching some data from the server to see which roles are assigned to current user.

The problem is that the method used to decide if an element should be shown or hidden is running an async call to the server to see the roles.

```
<div class="menu">
    <a ng-show="$root.hasRole(['admin', 'tech'])" ng-cloak>
        <i class="grid layout icon"></i> Users
    </a>
    ....
</div>
```

And the function `hasRole`:

```
controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'WhoAmI',
    function($scope, $rootScope, WhoAmI) {
        $rootScope.whoAmI = false;

        $scope.init = function() {
            WhoAmI.whoAmI(function(err, res) {
                $rootScope.whoAmI = res.user;
            });
        };

        $rootScope.hasRole = function(roles) {
            if(!$rootScope.whoAmI){
                return false;
            }
            _.forEach($rootScope.whoAmI.roles, function(v, k) {
                if (v.name in roles) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
])
```

As you would expect the elements render before the call return of that `init` function and they remain hidden. I attached that method `hasRole` to the `$rootScope` because I want it available through out the application.

Is there a way to pause the rendering until that `$rootScope.whoAmI` is not false any more or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: What is your definition of "render"?

Comment: I'm not sure what WhoAmI is, but if its not running on a digest cycle, you will need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the inner `return true` statement. It does return true, but from the inner function; the `hasRole()` function *still* returns false. So write it as:

```
    $rootScope.hasRole = function(roles) {
        var result = false;
        if(!$rootScope.whoAmI){
            return false;
        }
        _.forEach($rootScope.whoAmI.roles, function(v, k) {
            if (v.name in roles) {
                result = true;
                return false; // we have the result, stop iterating
            }
        });

        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way:

```
ng-show="$root.hasRole(['admin', 'tech'])"
```

You need to change it to: `ng-show="hasRole(['admin', 'tech'])"`

```
<div class="menu">
    <a ng-show="hasRole(['admin', 'tech'])" ng-cloak>
        <i class="grid layout icon"></i> Users
    </a>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: why is that wrong since the method is attached to the root scope